# How do you get dotenv to parse a list type environment variable?

Tags: node.js, configuration, dotenv

I am trying to define an environment variable of a 'list' type. I am using node and `dotenv` for config file parsing.

My `.env` file looks like this:

```
FOO=['a','b']
BAR=c
```

My code looks like this:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

for (const entry of process.env.FOO) {
  // do stuff
}
```

I realize that there are easy workarounds, but am wondering if there's a nicer way, such as by writing `FOO[]=['a','b']` or `dotenv.config(someOptionEnablingLists)`

Answer (score 0):

From [this GH issue](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/77) it appears as though there is not a nicer way, at least with dotenv by itself. I'm going with the [string splitting suggestion](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/77#issuecomment-116835883) for now.